# Nutch not moving documents to status DB_GONE

Tags: solr, nutch, web-crawler

From my understanding of Nutch, when Nutch is doing a recrawl and attempts to fetch a document that no longer exists, it generates a 404 and sets the status of that document to DB_GONE.  When I recrawl with Nutch it generates the 404 error , but when i do a:

```
readdb folder/crawldb - stats
```

it shows the file as db_unfetched as opposed to db_gone.  This is causing big problems as I cannot keep my Solr index up-to-date

If you want to check my Solr or Nutch set-up then follow my blog guides and it should be pretty identical: http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **db.fetch.retry.max** property in nutch configuration file. By default it set to 3. Only after maximum number of retries nutch will mark the document as **db_gone**. 
i.e. by default after 3rd retry nutch will mark a document **db_gone**, before that status will remain **db_unfetched**.